# Problems creating bootable USB-(SSD)-Drive

Tags: boot, usb, ssd, usb-drive, unetbootin

I am trying to create an bootable USB-SSD-Drive with Unetbootin.

Everything works well, when i am using an **ordinary USB 3.0 Thumb/Stick**.

**But** when i use a SSD-USB(3.0)-Drive, **only some/few** copied ISO's are booting.

**Examples:**

- UltimateBootCD_535.iso (boots from USB Thumb, but **not** from SSD-USB-Drive)
- linuxmint-17.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso (boots from USB Thumb, but **not** from SSD-USB-Drive)
- plopkexec.iso (boots well from USB-Thumb **AND** SSD-USB)

**Additional info's about my USB-SSD-Drive:**

The SSD-USB-Drive has an `msdos` partition table with only **1 primary** partition.
This partition is **fat32** formatted.

What could be the problem?
How can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Does your system has UEFI mode?

1. Try booting by switching off the secure boot in the bios setup of your computer. If it doesn't works you can try the next method.
2. Load the system default settings in the bios setup. If you are using windows to create bootable usb-ssd, try Rufus [ https://rufus.akeo.ie/ ] and create the bootable ssd by selecting "**GPT partition scheme for UEFI**". Then try to boot.

Comment: No, my Test-Notebook does not have UEFI. **Note**: When using an ordinary USB-(3.0)-Stick, it works! Same procedure with unetbootin and my USB-(3.0)-SSD and it won't boot.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to my own question, based on user496978 answer.

I just tried **Rufus** [https://rufus.akeo.ie/] (on Windows), to create a bootable USB-Drive of an ISO-File.
With **Rufus**, all tested ISO's are working/booting fine with/on my USB-SSD!

**Example:**
UltimateBootCD_535.iso is booting fine (from USB-SSD), when created using Rufus.
**But not** when created using Unetbootin.

The problem seems to be Unetbootin.

Cheers!